# How to start a local port on user's computer (Edited question)

Tags: java, php, python, c, localhost

sorry in the past I have not been able to formulate my question coherently. This will be my last try. =|

Basically, I want to do something like this website is doing: http://www.ninjavideo.net/video/56388. They are rendering an iframe that points to a port on localhost. You will see nothing in the iframe if you dont have their applet running (which can be found here: ninjavideo.net/applet.php ). I want to write a script that does something like what applet.php is doing, but I don't think they are using only php code as it won't run on computers that don't have php installed. Do you suppose they are using Java/C to do this?

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: What does "Java/C" mean?  Do you mean "Do you suppose they are using Java or C to do this?"  Or do you mean something else?  Java/C isn't meaningful.  Please fix it to make it clear what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [Applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applet) is basically a piece of Java code which is served by a webpage and is supposed to run at the client machine. You can learn more about Applets at [Sun's own Applet tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/). If you're green to Java as well, then I recommend to go through [Trials Covering the Basics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) first. Opening sockets (ports) using Java code is [covered here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

That PHP script is just serving the applet code from the server, so that the client can download it.

Comment: Just like I suspected... I'll dive into the tutorial right now! Thanks

Comment: Good luck. Don't forget to sign the applet as well. You're by default not allowed to open sockets from inside an applet due to security reasons.

Comment: oh yeah. It's not what your thinking... Im no hacker just a noob. hehe. Thanks

Comment: You **need** to open a socket (port) whenever you want to achieve the same :)

Comment: [b]Stop[/b] giving me ideas =D

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in PHP using a ready-to-run Apache setup (there are some that are ready to run from a USB key, should be possible to make into something that a client can install, but is complicated, see e.g. [**this tutorial**](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/run-webserver-usb-stick-windows-guide_t14970.html)) or a product like [**NuSphere Dock**](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm):

> PhpDock is a deployment platform for PHP applications.
>
> PhpDock enables you to deploy any PHP web application as a Stand Alone Windows Desktop application w/o any changes in the code.
>
> PhpDock combines NuSphere's powerful embeded Srv webserver and browser components.

I would usually say that if you are looking to build a Windows application, you should go with a tool that is aimed at just that, i.e. C++, C#, Java, the .NET platform, Delphi, and the likes. But if you need some kind of daemon or local web server, you may actually be well off with a product bringing a web server to the desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will look into PhpDock for sure. But what do you mean by, "bringing a web server to the desktop"?

Comment: I mean, taking web server software like Apache / PHP and running it on a client's computer. It's possible as I said, but horribly messy. Check out phpdock, I don't know the specific product but I've been very happy with their PHP IDE for years.